# Phonegap Plugin Push & Node-gcm NotRegistered

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, cordova, phonegap-plugins

So I have seen other people with this issue post on here. Nothing seems to right with what I am having. Here is the steps of my issues:

1) I installed my Ionic app onto my phone.

2) Setup my sender key and API key with the google console.
3) Created my node-gcm server.

4) Sent notifications to my phone using my phonegap-plugin-push device token.

5) uninstalled my app

6) reinstalled the app.

7) tried sending notifications, and now I am getting a NotRegistered Error by GCM.

I cross checked all of my keys: server, sender, device. All are correct. I cannot figure out why after reinstallation of the app, i get a notregistered error. Here are the tools I am using:
Ionic framework, android phone, NodeJS server, Node-gcm, google dev console, phonegap-plugin-push

And lastly, Code:

```js
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup, $rootScope, $http, $state) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    var push = PushNotification.init({
        android: {
          senderID: "7821....1490",
       sound: "true",
       vibration: "true"
        },
        browser: {
            pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
        },
        ios: {
            alert: "true",
            badge: true,
            sound: "true",
         vibration: "true",
         clearBadge: true
        },
        windows: {}
    });
    push.on('registration', function(data) {
        console.log("Device Token: " + data.registrationId);
        $rootScope.devToken = data.registrationId;
    })
```

```js
var message = new gcm.Message();
    message.addData('title', 'Alert');
    message.addData('message', 'Message From: '+ messageUser + '\n' + 'Message Text: ' + messageText);
    //message.addData('image', image);
    sender.send(message, android, function (err, response) {
     if(err) {}
           else {
      console.log(response.results);
      //response is NotRegistered, unregister devices
      for (var i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++) {
       if (response.results[i].error == 'NotRegistered') {
        console.log("ERROR");
       }
      }
     }    
    });
```

I am willing to work through this with you. Just know, I have checked all keys, and all are the correct keys. When I reinstalled the app, I got a new device token and I am trying to push to that new device token.

Answer (score 2):

OK! FOR ANYONE WITH THIS PROBLEM READ HERE!

With push plugin, on app uninstall. It does not clear all the data. I am storing the device token in a scope variable and storing it in local storage. On app uninstall, go to settings and clear all data before uninstalling. Once you reinstall, you will get a new token and it should work!